# Modal se muestra solo un milisegundo

Tags: bootstrap, modal

Estoy con un proyecto php y tengo problemas con el modal: al lanzar el evento con el botón solo se muestra el modal un milisegundo. No hay manera y no veo error:
Este es el lanzador:

```html
<div class="box-header with-border"> 
       <!-- Button trigger modal -->
       <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#anadeUsuario">
        Añadir usuario
       </button>             
</div>
```

Y este es el modal:

```html
   <!-- Modal --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="anadeUsuario"  role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header">    
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button> 
            <h3 class="modal-title fs-5" id="mySmallModalLabel">Registro de usuario</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Limpiar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Dura un milisegundo en pantalla (tan rápido que no se puede hacer captura)

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap tienes?

Comment: La versión de Bootstrap es importante aquí. Si es Bootstrap 5, tenés que tener en cuenta [los cambios en esta versión](/a/477556). Te aseguro que con los cambios mencionados en esa respuesta, se mostrará correctamente el modal.